# Anylogic PLE version 8.7.8 : 3d Objects are not visible

Tags: 3d, anylogic

I am using Anylogic PLE version 8.7.8, on macOS 12.01. The 3d objects in anylogic are not visible in my model. This started when I was still using Anylogic version 8.7.6 so I uninstalled anylogic and installed it again to no success. I even upgraded my Anylogic version to version 8.7.8 but the problem still persists.

Can anyone help?

[Image of 3d object in anylogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sYR7.jpg)

Comment: Can you see them at runtime in 3D? (Sometimes, more complex 3D files are not shown correctly in the IDE as in your screenshot)

Comment: No, when I run the model the object does not show up, I just see a blank screen.

Comment: Did you try with the existing example models? Do they show normally, in IDE and at runtime?

Comment: Well I just ran the distribution center example model, the 3d objects seem to showing up in my IDE as well as in during runtime. The problem seems to arise when  I want to add the 3d objects into my own models.

Comment: ok, might be MacOS then, check with support@anylogic.com

Comment: Alright thanks, will do.