# AnyLogic behaving strange on Mac. Bug or configuration issue?

Tags: anylogic

I work with AnyLogic PLE on both Windows and Mac and have been running into weird random issues on Mac that I don't see on Windows like my agent animations not showing up. Is this a bug or do I not have something configured correctly?

I put a simulation together on windows 11, then opened it on Mac OS Monterey, and a 3D animation of an aircraft is no longer visible. Using Anylogic 8.7.9 PLE.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please provide mroe details like your PLE version, what operating system version you are working on and EXACTLY what is the issue you are experiencing, with screenshots and comparisons between Windows and Mac. What is the expected result and what is the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the exact same model in Windows and in Mac and the results are different then it is a bug and you need to notify AnyLogic support.

There is no special setup for Mac, or Linux, AnyLogic should be platform-independent.

That said there are some know bugs on 3D objects - see here [Anylogic PLE version 8.7.8 : 3d Objects are not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70180674/anylogic-ple-version-8-7-8-3d-objects-are-not-visible)

Answer (score 0):

Received a reply from AnyLogic and this is a known bug. Was told, as a work around, that agent animations can be replaced with basic shapes from the presentation library and now the simulation runs as it should.